# How to override RabbitMQ docker image's default user and password

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I'm trying to disable the guest/guest login on the rabbitmq docker container and I'm able to successfully disable the managements default user however i can still connect to rabbitmq with the default guest/guest and can't connect with user/password.

Here is my compose file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: 'rabbitmq:3-management'
    ports:
      - '15672:15672'
      - '5672:5672'
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=password
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user
      - RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=password
      - RABBITMQ_USERNAME=user
```

I cant login to localhost:15672 (the management ui) with guest/guest only with user/password which is what i want however i can login to rabbitmq localhost:5672 with guest/guest and not user/password.

Comment: Did you set `RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_*` after starting the container?

Comment: @snahor sorry not sure what you mean (not to much experience with docker). I just ran this file with docker-compose up -d

Comment: What I meant is if you started the container without setting those vars. When the container starts and `RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_...` are not set, `guest` will be used. If this is your case, you either recreate the container or just create the user with `rabbitmqctl`. Does this make sense?

Comment: When I go into the container I can see that the environment variables are set. Would that require creating a different entrypoint file?

Comment: If i create a volume mount I am able to get the desired behavior. I don't know why this is but it does work.

Comment: I had changed my `guest` password, and my container instance (`rabbitmq:3.12-management`) basically quit working because it couldn't log in. Setting those four environment vars to `guest` and the new password, fixed it!  Just an FYI for anyone stumbling upon this post.